# getting at a deep property for a lambda Expression

Tags: linq, reflection, lambda

I have some code thus:

```
CaseHeaderComparer CaseComparer = new CaseHeaderComparer();
List<CaseHeader> CasesToProcess = new List<CaseHeader>();

foreach (GroupField fld in Fields)
{
    //get the field property - ie. Division
    System.Reflection.PropertyInfo piField = typeof(CaseHeader).GetProperty(fld.GroupFieldType.PropertyName);
    //get the item property - ie. DivisionID
    System.Reflection.PropertyInfo piItem = piField.PropertyType.GetProperty(fld.GroupFieldType.ValueMember);

    foreach (CaseHeader ch in ToProcess)
    {
        object chItem = piField.GetValue(ch, null);
        Guid ItemID = chItem != null ? (Guid)piItem.GetValue(chItem, null) : Guid.Empty;

        if (fld.Items.Select(i => i.ItemID).Contains(ItemID))
        {
            CasesToProcess.Add(ch);
        }
    }
    ToProcess = ToProcess.Except(CasesToProcess, CaseComparer).ToList();
}
```

Which I would like to convert to to use linq and lambdas - i got fairly close with some help from here yesterday with this:

```
List<CaseHeader> ToProcess = ....;
CaseHeaderComparer CaseComparer = new CaseHeaderComparer();
IEnumerable<CaseHeader> CasesToProcess = new BackingSheetCaseHeader[] { };
foreach (GroupField fld in Fields)
{
    //get the field property - ie. Division
    System.Reflection.PropertyInfo piField = typeof(CaseHeader).GetProperty(fld.GroupFieldType.PropertyName);
    //get the item property - ie. DivisionID
    System.Reflection.PropertyInfo piItem = piField.PropertyType.GetProperty(fld.GroupFieldType.ValueMember);

    CasesToProcess.Union(
        ToProcess
            .Where(c => fld.Items.Select(i => i.ItemID)
                .Contains((piField.GetValue(c, null) != null ? (Guid)piItem.GetValue(piField.GetValue(c, null), null) : Guid.Empty)))
                , CaseComparer);
}
```

this works but someone pointed out that i could do something along the lines of this..

```
var hdr = typeof(CaseHeader);
var param = Expression.Parameter(hdr);
var cond = Expression.Condition(
    Expression.NotEqual(param, Expression.Constant(null, hdr))
,   Expression.Property(param, fld.GroupFieldType.PropertyName) <<-- but this needs to go 2 deep.. as above the item property..
,   Expression.Constant(Guid.Empty)
);
var lambda = (Func<MyCaseObj,Guid>)Expression.Lambda(cond, param).Compile();
```

then i could do

```
var CasesToProcess = (from csh in CasesInGroup 
    where lambda(csh).In(fld.Items.Select(i => i.ItemID)) 
    select csh);
```

but the 2 deep bit is stumping me
as above I need to get to the fld.GroupFieldType.ValueMember property of the fld.GroupFieldType.PropertyName property of the CaseHeader..
**the value of the first level may be null**..

can anyone give me some pointers, or somewhere to have a read up on this

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be that you don't need to build your `Expression` *manually* at all. The C# compiler can translate lambda expressions into `Func<>`s **and** `Expression<Func<>>`s. Both the following work:

```
        var func = (Func<int, bool>)(i => i == 2);
        var expression = (Expression<Func<int, bool>>)(i => i == 2);
```

after which `expression.Compile()` is a `Func<int,bool>` with the same behaviour as `func`! So try just

```
var expression = (Expression<Func<MyCaseObj,Guid>>)
    (c => fld.Items.Select(i => i.ItemID)
          .Contains((piField.GetValue(c, null) != null 
                     ? (Guid)piItem.GetValue(piField.GetValue(c, null), null) 
                     : Guid.Empty))
    );
```

and take it from there.